# Yii::createWebApplication() returns "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection."

Tags: php, yii, behat

I've updated MAMP right now. With old version of MAMP all worked fine.

I am working with Yii and behat. All Behat's Backrounds has this sentence:

```
Then I create Yii application
```

And this is the phrase in FeatureContext:

```
/**
 * @Then /^I create Yii application$/
 */
public function iCreateYiiApplication() {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii/framework/yii.php';
    try {
        $app = Yii::createWebApplication(array(
                    'basePath' => __DIR__ . '/../../app',
                    'components' => array(
                        'db' => require __DIR__ . '/../../app/protected/config/db.php',
                    )
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

This snippet works with the same db configutation of application. The nice thing is that all works fine in web browser. But qhen I run ./bin/behat, ... all stops to work and test fail:

```
$ ./bin/behat features/login.feature:3

@BehavioralDrivenDevelopment
..F-------..F-------..F----------..F----..F-------------------..F----------------..F
-------------..F-------------..F---------------..F--------------..F-----------------
---..F---------------..F-----------------..F---------------------------------..F----
------..F------------..F------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------

(::) failed steps (::)

01. CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.
    In step `Then database is ready'. # InheritedFeatureContext::databaseIsReady()
    From scenario background.         # features/login.feature:3
```

The only difference I know is php version: MAMP works with php5.5 and console with php 5.4.16 installed by brew. So, ... Any idea of what connection does not work?

Comment: I haven't worked with this before but the first thing that came to my mind is thatthe `config` settings for the web view and the command line view are different. Maybe you should check.

Comment: Mmmm where I can find php.ini of cli?